# flywaydb baseline script doesnt run

Tags: flyway

i am confused why my baseline script is not being run.

i followed this instructions
[existing db baseline](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/existing.html)

when i run the following clean, baseline, migrate
the baseline script doesnt get run.
i am expecting the V1__BaseLine.sql to be from but from the log it doesnt get run.

```
the schema reports

1   1   1   BaseLine    BASELINE    BaseLine        OEOWN   11/AUG/15 11:25:56.881000000 AM 0   1
2   2   1.3 create  SQL V1_3__create.sql    1454099419  OEOWN   11/AUG/15 11:25:56.985000000 AM 3   0


scripts
----------
V1__BaseLine.sql
V1_3__create.sql
V1_4__create_other.sql
```

maven log

```
 --- flyway-maven-plugin:3.2.1:clean (default-cli) @ SmartFormsService ---
[INFO] Flyway 3.2.1 by Boxfuse
[INFO] Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe (Oracle 11.2)
[INFO] Cleaned schema "OEOWN" (execution time 00:00.073s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:3.2.1:baseline (default-cli) @ SmartFormsService ---
[INFO] Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe (Oracle 11.2)
[INFO] Creating Metadata table: "OEOWN"."schema_version"
[INFO] Schema baselined with version: 1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:3.2.1:migrate (default-cli) @ SmartFormsService ---
[INFO] Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe (Oracle 11.2)
[INFO] Validated 3 migrations (execution time 00:00.000s)
[INFO] Current version of schema "OEOWN": 1
[INFO] Migrating schema "OEOWN" to version 1.3 - create
[ERROR] Migration of schema "OEOWN" to version 1.3 failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
```

any help?

-lp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyway baseline is meant to be run against the DBs where you do NOT want to run the V1 baseline script (the DBs that should not be recreated from scratch)

The V1 baseline script is only meant for new or cleaned DB instances, where Flyway baseline as NOT been run.

What you did is running both Flyway baseline and attempting to run the V1 baseline script, which can never work.

To simplify:

- DEV: Clean the DB and run the V1 baseline script
- PROD: Do NOT clean the DB and run flyway baseline

Comment: @AxelFontaine Hi Axel, if I baseline an existing database then run a few new scripts. How do I undo all the new scripts? I tried doing a flyway.clean() but got  org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to clean schema "FEED"